# 'which' location different from executable location

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal

I'm trying to install ruby/rubygems on the latest version of 10.6. I used MacPorts to install `ruby` after noticing that my version was old. `ruby` was installed into `/opt/local/bin`.

I changed `.bash_profile` and added:

`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

When I `echo $PATH`, I get:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

So when I type `which ruby` I get:

`/opt/local/bin/ruby`

Which works correctly. However, when I type `which gem` I get:

`/opt/local/bin/gem`

When using `gem -environment` I get (`gem` is in the above directory):

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory
```

I'm completely open to uninstalling everything and starting over if necessary. I'm just not sure why it's still trying to grab it from `/usr/bin`!

Answer (score 4):

The default `gem` is a function and they get called before $PATH and also before the command `hash`.

Try playing with `hash` (or clearing it with `hash -r` ) to see if your path isn't getting a say in which gem to call.

`type gem` will confirm whether yur gem is really a function...

Comment: To elaborate a bit: if an outdated hashed location is the issue, then `hash -d gem` will clear the entry for `gem`, after which the instance given by `which gem` should be the one that gets called.  Opening a new `bash` instance should also clear the hashed commands.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess. I ended up removing all versions of ruby and MacPorts and compiling 1.9.2 from source. Everything is working fine now.